# How to list the pods running in a particular zone?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How to list the pods running in a particular zone?
And suppose my cluster is configured into multiple zones, how to ensure pods are distributed into every zone?

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457455/multizone-kubernetes-cluster-and-affinity-how-to-distribute-application-per-zon

Answer (score 1):

Topology key zone value is a label applied on nodes and so you can get the nodes with 'zone-value' and list pods of those nodes.
Somethig like below,

`kubectl get nodes -l zone:<zone value> -o json | jq '.items[].metadata.name' | xargs -I worker sh -c 'kubectl get pods -o wide | grep worker'`

Answer (score -1):

```
kubectl get nodes --show-labels|awk 'NR == 1 {next} {print $1,$6}'|awk -F "/" '{print $1,$NF}'|awk '{print $1,$NF}'|awk -F "=" '{print $1,$NF}'|awk '{print $1,"\t",$NF;}'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?